# john failed to crack .zip file?

Tags: john-the-ripper, zip

I have a .zip file and I want to crack its password using john.

first I use **zip2john**:

[image]

then I use **john** for cracking the password:

[image]

but ***after 10 seconds, john stop cracking and exit***.

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is standard! Either the corresponding password wasn’t found in your password list or the the hash has been cracked before.

You can check to see if it’s already been cracked by doing:

```
john —show <hash file>
```

E.g.

```
john —show ai.txt
```

A similar question was asked here: [John the Ripper - Can't get cracked MD5 hash to show](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152061/john-the-ripper-cant-get-cracked-md5-hash-to-show)